# Azure. Subscription Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

Once I elevated myself from Global Administrator to User Access Administrator, I'm able to see 7 "Free Trial" Subscriptions in the root Management Group, yet from the Subscriptions section I can only see 6. Once I click that one Subscription that only shows up in the root Management Group I get "Resource not found". 
[image]
Why is this happening?

Comment: Check if the setting is `Yes`, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7Wj.png

Comment: Yes, it is set to `Yes`.

Comment: If so, I think the subscription is not existing.

Comment: If the Subscription doesn't exist, why is it listed in Management Groups then?

Comment: Not sure, I could not test for you on my side. But if the setting is `Yes`, you are the [`User Access Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) in `Root` scope, you can see all the subscriptions in the tenant. Did you cancel this subscription?

Comment: The only thing I see is pictured on the screenshot, I can't tell if the Subscription cancelled or not.

Comment: If so, I recommend you to contact the azure support.